# update_all works but update_attributes doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, update-attributes, update-all

The two codes below are for updating the database.

The first version, which uses the 'update_attributes' property is not working

```
@existing_exp = Emiexperiment.find(:first, :conditions => [ "EMI_COM_ID = ? and EMI_SUB_FK = ?", "EMI_999", "7789"])

@existing_exp.update_attributes(
                          :EMI_STATUS => "present",
                          :EMI_ADD_STATUS => "weak"
                         )
```

However, the code below, which uses the 'update_All' attribute seems to work great.

```
Emiexperiment.update_all "EMI_STATUS = 'present', EMI_ADD_STATUS = 'moderate'", ["EMI_COM_ID = ? and EMI_SUB_FK = ?", "EMI_999", "7789"]
```

Here is the class code for Emiexpression:

```
class Emiexperiment < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "EMI_EXPERIMENT"
set_primary_key "EMI_OID"
attr_accessible :EMI_STATUS, :EMI_ADD_STATUS, :EMI_COM_ID, :EMI_SUB_FK


belongs_to :sub, :foreign_key => "EMI_SUB_FK"


end
```

I am confused as to why this is so.

I am not using any validation in my 'Emiexperiment' model.

Any hint on this is most appreciated. Many many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you specify the Rails version?

Comment: Please expand on "not working", are you getting an error? Also please show the code that creates @existing_EMI

Comment: Sorry it should have been '@existing_exp'

Answer (score 1):

You may want `attr_accessor` for those fields.  `attr_accessor` is a ruby method that makes a getter and a setter.
`attr_accessible` is a Rails method that allows you to pass in values to a mass assignment:, e.g. `update_attributes(attrs)`.

Comment: Further clarification, any attributes that are not called out in `attr_accessor` will be ignored if they are passed into the `update_attributes` methods